# Indicating dynamic nature of certain parts of dataset in Datastudio charts

Tags: charts, looker-studio

I am using Data studio for the visualization of a data structure that automatically updates on a weekly basis. The data structure is dynamic in a way that indices that have a time-stamp that is higher than 3 months ago are susceptible to certain change. So in a time-chart: frequency values can change in this "recent" time-slot. Coming from Tableau, there are many options to indicate this in the visualization/dashboard such as making this 3 month area in the chart grey or the bars grey. However, I did not find any solution in Data studio to do it this way. I have thought about making a grey element behind the chart. However, this would be a static element that won't change size based on chosen time-range (thus rendering it not useful). I would like to know if there is a way in Data studio to reach this goal or something similar to this.

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is to make two metrics - 1 being within 3 months and the other being before 3 months. You can then add both to the chart and they'll have different colours.

But other than that no. Data Studio clearly isn't as advanced as other visualisation products.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific visualization need that cannot be achieved with the built-in charts, you can use the new [community visualizations](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/visualization/) feature.